# Index names of all the files in a plain text file

Tags: bash, command-line, files

I've got this directory full of images, and I can do this:

```
echo *.jpg
image1.jpg image2.jpg image3.jpg # and so on
```

How can I get the output in a plain text file in this format?

```
image1.jpg
image2.jpg
image3.jpg
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Avoid using `ls`, bash globs can do it better

```
printf '%s\n' *.jpg >output_file
```

Comment: Why is bash globbing better than using `ls`?

Comment: If you just want to print the list, `ls` is good. But if you want to process the files, glob is better: `for file in *` will work for files with spaces in their names, while `ls | while read file` will not.

Comment: *@choroba.* I am completely in favour of using bash globbing here, but you can easily get `ls` to handle multiple spaces in a filename by using `IFS=$'\n'`. Yes, it is more of a hassle, but it isn't a show-stopper for `ls`. The main restriction with output from `ls` is that it can't easily handle `\n` in filenames other than via the `-b` option (print octal escapes for nongraphic characters) which makes it rather impractical when compared to using globbing...  Come to think of it: when a filename **does** have `\n` in it, then perhaps `ls -b` is the easiset way to hanlde it in an output file.

Comment: Ok, `ls` writes non-printable characters 'as is' when the output is sent to a pipe (I was misled from the terminal output). However, `ls` is a further process to start, and I try to avoid it whenever possible.

Comment: Can this be done recursively?

Comment: And one more thing, how can I avoid files ending with `sm.jpg` avoided. I know it's going to add another layer of complexity, but I need it.

Comment: @Oxwivi: you can do `shopt -s globstar` and then `printf '%s\n' **/*.jpg`, but at this point I would switch to `find`.

Comment: @Oxwivi: `printf '%s\n' **/!(*sm).jpg`

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer `find` over `ls`. With find you can specify a lot of options, such as directory depth (min and max), access/modified time, use regular expressions and a lot more. Have a look at the find manpage.

```
runejuhl@lapaz:~/Pictures$ find . -iname '*.jpg'|head
./2011/03/09/CIMG9447.JPG
./2011/03/09/CIMG9445.JPG
./2011/03/09/CIMG9444.JPG
./2011/03/09/CIMG9442.JPG
./2011/03/09/CIMG9443.JPG
./2011/03/09/CIMG9440.JPG
./2011/03/09/CIMG9441.JPG
./2011/03/09/CIMG9446.JPG
./2011/06/26/CIMG9512.JPG
./2011/06/26/CIMG9585.JPG

runejuhl@lapaz:~/Pictures$ find . -maxdepth 2 -iname '*.jpg' |head
./Webcam/2012-01-10-120822.jpg
./Webcam/2010-11-08-192524.jpg
./Webcam/2012-01-10-170146.jpg
./Webcam/2012-01-10-120928_4.jpg
./Webcam/2012-01-10-120835_4.jpg
./Webcam/2012-01-10-120928_3.jpg
./Webcam/2012-01-10-120828.jpg
./Webcam/2012-01-10-120928_2.jpg
./Webcam/2012-01-10-120945_1.jpg
./Webcam/2012-01-10-120945_2.jpg
```

To get only the filename, you can use the `-printf` argument:

> -printf format
>
> True; print format on the standard output, interpreting `\' escapes and`%' directives.  Field widths and precisions can be
>   specified as  with the `printf' C function.  Please note that many of
>   the fields are printed as %s rather than %d, and this may mean that
>   flags don't work as you might expect.  This also means that the`-'
>   flag does work (it forces fields to be left-aligned).  Unlike -print,
>   -printf does not add a  newline at the end of the string.

(look at the man page for more information)

To print only the filename, you'd use printf with "%f":

```
runejuhl@lapaz:~/Pictures$ find . -maxdepth 2 -iname '*.jpg' -printf '%f\n' |head
2012-01-10-120822.jpg
2010-11-08-192524.jpg
2012-01-10-170146.jpg
2012-01-10-120928_4.jpg
2012-01-10-120835_4.jpg
2012-01-10-120928_3.jpg
2012-01-10-120828.jpg
2012-01-10-120928_2.jpg
2012-01-10-120945_1.jpg
2012-01-10-120945_2.jpg
```

If using xargs, and passing the filename in this way, it might be a good idea to use "%f\0"  and `xargs -0` to use null delimiters.

When you feel like it, have a look at the `-print0` argument and a real good look at `xargs` or parallel

Comment: Is it possible to only retrieve and save the names of the files minus the directory?

Comment: Yes, no problem. You can use the <code>-type</code> argument to specify which types.
(I just read the question again, this isn't what you're looking for. I'll update my reply later today.)